# deployment sharepoint webpart

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2007

I am working on sharepoint webpart and i will be developing webpart on my local machine that has visual studio.net on windows XP. My sharepoint is installed on another web server. how would i deploy  from my local machine? what kind of rights do i need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you will create it as a Feature and deploy it as a solution package. I have outlined the process in a two-part blog post here:

http://codersbarn.com/?tag=/webpart

By default, SharePoint Web applications are only allowed to run with a very restrictive trust level of WSS_Minimal. If we want to have our Web Part deployed to the bin folder, then in order for it to run we must do one of two things: either set the trust level to WSS_Medium or WSS_Full in the web.config, or create a custom CAS policy that will allow this assembly's managed code to run.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i am very beginner in SP and i have posted this question here, would you help me to start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065927/creating-a-custom-control-for-sharepoint-web-part

Comment: do you have setup by step on how to create a feature ? that will be very helpful.

Comment: Here you go: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/In+the+Office/Creating-and-Deploying-a-Feature-for-Windows-SharePoint-Services-V3

Comment: thanks for the screencast, what i dont understand is that... in the screencast did he has sp installed on a different server and ui was on his local machine?

Comment: i have sp 2007 installed on server and what WSS version should i be installing? and can you provide me the link, i did google and get so many different version.

Comment: You should do your dev work on a local VM and then deploy the Web Part. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581050/sharepoint-development-environment-setup

Comment: so you saying that i should have a VM with Sharepoint,Windows Server and Visual Studio on it?

Comment: @AbuHamzah let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2506/discussion-between-irishchieftain-and-abu-hamzah)